# Composite literal and fields from an embedded type

Tags: go, embedding, composite-literals

I was working on a sample program to answer another question here on SO and found myself somewhat baffled by the fact that the following code will not compile;

https://play.golang.org/p/wxBGcgfs1o

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    FName string
    LName string
}

type B struct {
    A
}

func (a *A) Print() {
     fmt.Println(a.GetName())
}

func (a *A) GetName() string {
     return a.FName
}

func (b *B) GetName() string {
     return b.LName
}

func main() {
    a := &A{FName:"evan", LName:"mcdonnal"}
    b := &B{FName:"evan", LName:"mcdonnal"}

    a.Print()
    b.Print()
}
```

The error is;

```
/tmp/sandbox596198095/main.go:28: unknown B field 'FName' in struct literal
/tmp/sandbox596198095/main.go:28: unknown B field 'LName' in struct literal
```

Is it possible to set the value of fields from an embedded type in a static initializer? How? To me this seems like a compiler bug; if I didn't have the sources in front of me and was familiar with type I would be beating my head against a wall saying "clearly FName exists on B what is the compiler saying!?!?!".

Quickly, to preempt typical answers I am aware that the closest working syntax is this `b := &B{A{FName:"evan", LName:"mcdonnal"}}` but that syntax is in my opinion conceptually contradictory to embedding so I would be disappointed if it is the only option. If this is the only way, is it a short coming of the Go compiler or is there actually a theoretical limitation that would prevent a compiler from interpreting the syntax in my non-working example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error: unknown field in struct literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098460/getting-error-unknown-field-in-struct-literal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a compiler *bug* but a design decision. The language spec just states:

> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.

I guess the reasoning behind this is to avoid ambiguity. There are a few rules to resolve name conflicts when using selectors, and they would have to be complicated in order to allow what you're suggesting. On top of that, it might create ambiguity if you're using an existing instance of an embedded struct inside a struct literal of the embedding type.

EDIT: Here's an example where this approach might backfire:

Think of a case where you have A embedding B, and an instance of A you want to embed:

```
type A {
   X int
}

type B {
   A
}
```

It's simple enough to do

```
b := B{ X: 1 }
```

And infer what should be done.
But what if we already have an instance of A? This doesn't make sense:

```
a := A { X: 1 }

b := B { X: 2, A: a, }
```

are you first assigning 2 to a zero instance of A and then assigning the initialized instance of A over it? And is it identical to:

```
b := B { A: a, X: 2 }  ?
```

It breaks the assumption that initialization order is irrelevant in a composite literal with field names.

Comment: Apt quote from the spec :). But I don't follow your guess at the reason. I don't see the big difference to supporting `b := B{FName:"x", "LName:"y"}` given than it supports `b := B{}; b.FName="x"; b.LName="y"`.

Comment: Yeah that quote clearly states my code won't compile. I agree with @DaveC though... If it was a conscious design decision, it was the wrong one. Dave's comment points out my MAJOR problem with the design. On one line I access the field without complaint, on another the compiler claims it doesn't exist on that struct. That's fundamentally a contradiction.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, great addition/edit. It makes sense that there should be no issue with the compiler doing the assignments in a composite literal in whatever order it feels like. Having to explicitly say either `B.X=2; B.A=a` *or* `B.A=a; B.X=2` on the other hand makes it unambiguous/clear.