# Getting error: unknown field in struct literal

Tags: go

I am trying to run this code:

```
type NullInt64 struct {
    sql.NullInt64
}

func ToNullInt64(s string) NullInt64 {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    return NullInt64{Int64: int64(i), Valid: err == nil}
}
```

but I get this error:

```
..\sql\sql.go:27: unknown NullInt64 field 'Int64' in struct literal
..\sql\sql.go:27: unknown NullInt64 field 'Valid' in struct literal
```

Comment: I looked at the other post, but I could still not fix my problem.

Comment: By looking at the other post, I tried this: return NullInt64{NullInt64: NullInt64{Int64: int64(i), Valid: err == nil}}. But I get the same error.

Comment: The inner `NullInt64` should be `sql.NullInt64`.

Comment: Like this you mean? return NullInt64{sql.NullInt64{Int64: int64(i), Valid: err == nil}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To initialize the embedded sql.NullInt64, you have to write:

```
NullInt64{sql.NullInt64{Int64: int64(i), Valid: err == nil}}
```

or, if your NullInt64 struct contains other fields which you don't want to initialize explicitly, you can access the embedded field by using its type:

```
NullInt64{NullInt64: sql.NullInt64{Int64: int64(i), Valid: err == nil}}
```