# Embedded structs opposed situation

Tags: go

We have 3 types:

```
type A struct {
    B
    C
}
type B struct {
    x int
    y string
}
type C struct {
    z string
}
```

because of how fields and methods of an anonymous field are [promoted](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), we can access fields of the anonymous field `B` in `A` like

```
var a A
a.x = 0
```

It is very obvious that type `B` & `C` embed in `A`, so we expect `A` to be equivalent to:

```
type D struct {
    x int
    y string
    z string
}
```

#### What did you expect to see?

We expect that we can write composite literals of type `A` like that:

```
a := A{x: 2}
```

#### What did you see instead?

This compile error:

```
unknown field 'x' in struct literal of type A
```

#### Our Question

Why isn't it possible to write composite literals for `A` in that way, as it would for the type `D`?

https://play.golang.org/p/uM5JkO5EvE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nested struct initialization literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325496/nested-struct-initialization-literals)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composite literal and fields from an embedded type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979056/composite-literal-and-fields-from-an-embedded-type)

Answer (score 2):

Rob 'Commander' Pike explained it [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/LUF4LpXVU8g/likbOsXTXvwJ).

He wrote there:

> It might one day, but as it stands the requirement to provide more 
>   information is more robust against changes in the data types.

If I understand and interpret that correctly, it is basically a safety measure for you. The compiler will yell at you, if the struct definition doesn't match the composite literal.

In your example, the definition of `A` might change -- in a later change (as in much later, like years) -- to:

```
    type A struct {
        x int
        y string
        z string
    }
```

later, but `x`, `y` and `z` might represent different things than before and therefore it is better, that you have to change all your literals to
not get silently corrupt data of some kind.

That is a deliberate choice. The wording in the language specification is:

> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.

So you can use the field `x` of the field `B` as if it was a field of `A` except for composite literals.

And the types

```
type A struct {
    B
    C
}
```

and

```
type A struct {
    x int
    y string
    z string
}
```

really are two different things. The former contains two fields `B` and `C`, and the latter three fields `x`, `y` and `z`. The former just has some syntactic sugar to access the field `x` of the field `B` with a shorthand. So if `a` is a variable of the former type `A`, `a.x` is syntactic sugar for `a.B.x`.

Comment: thanks for answer. but I explain in question why we can use a.x = 0 !!? if it is safely choose, why this model(a.x = 0) work? we must think differently in same thing!!

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly use `B` (and `C`) when initializing `A`:

`a = A{B{x: 2}, C{}}`